# Invalid _rev format when _rev is null

Tags: java, cloudant

I am attempting to create a document with a user supplied `_id`. I am seeing this error:

```
com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: 400 Bad Request at http://localhost:5984/db/FGH-Z6IC5NHX8RS1HJ03. Error: bad_request. Reason: Invalid rev format.
```

I have confirmed that the `_rev` is `null` when I call `db.save(obj);`. Clicking on the link and searching it in the database also reveals that it does not exist.

I've also traced the call to make sure it was calling the correct `save(obj)`, and it is. As far as I'm aware, it is using the `newEntity=true` flag.

One thing I am doing a bit differently is I'm supplying my own `GsonBuilder` via [FxGson](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/fx-gson), since I am using JavaFx and its `Property` fields.

No idea why I am getting this error as everything looks good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a document, the rev field should be omitted.  Try to remove the property from the object before saving it to the database.

Comment: This worked, though I am not happy about it. I want to `serializeNulls()` and this, along with a similar `_attachments` error, makes it so I can not without another step.